# Is LGE Optimus L5 as ARMv7a device?

Tags: android, arm

Is `LGE Optimus L5` a `ARMv7a` device?

I made FAT APK with `armeabi` and `armeabi-v7a` native codes.

`LGE Optimus L5` runs `armeabi` lib and I expected it to run `armeabi-v7a` lib.

UPDATE: I am sure L5 has ARMv7 CPU. (It even has NEON and VFPv4)
Android System info also tells what I know from wiki. But it runs armeabi lib instead of armeabi-v7a lib in app I compiled.

What could be wrong? Could I miss to add some param somewhere (AndroidManifest.xml ???) or L5 has OS settings to run armeabi libs instead of armeabi-v7a libs?

UPDATE:

If I compile FAT and delete `armeabi` folder or compile only `armeabi-v7a` then LGE L5 runs ARMv7 code if I have both ARMv5 and ARMv7 then LGE L5 runs ARMv5 code.

Why? It should run most optimized code for that CPU! I wish to know how to force to to use ARMv7 code.

Comment: try installing "Android info" app and check,may be it will give you details you need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens due to the bug in Android ICS

- http://www.moodstocks.com/2012/03/20/ice-cream-sandwich-why-native-code-support-sucks/
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-ndk/N8FLjvM81pg/2rYeClQZcckJ